# IE8: CSS relatively positioned child overflows parent

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having issues with IE8 and hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

So I have a parent which is relatively positioned. The parent has two children of which one is absolute and one relative in position. When you hover over the parent, the `left` values of the children change and the relatively positioned one is supposed to overflow and be hidden.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sladkoff/s7ub9zL8/3/

"Normal" Browsers hide the relative child if it overflows but IE8 will still display it no matter what.

I'm not quite sure if anyone will be able to test this in IE8 thought, since I had to open `http://jsfiddle.net/draft/` to see it there. Don't know how this works for guests viewing the fiddle. I guess you need to have it open in e.g. Chrome and then switch to the mentioned link in IE. Let me know if it works...

Any Advice?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried z-index?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Oh god, that was genious... How did I not try that. Worked like a charm. Thanks!!! Edit: Want to answer the question or should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use z-index to position your objects in the stacking order you need.

```
.absolute {
     z-index:1;
}
.relative {
    z-index:2;
}
```